# Write a function that receives an array of names and returns them in a string with , between them. The final two must be separated by and

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm starting JavaScript learning program but in the very first day they told us to solve the following problem where I'm completly stuck after a day

> Write a function that receives an array of names and returns them in a
>   string with , between them. The final two must be separated by and.

They gave us this example

```
var names;

names = [ "Canada", "Mexico", "Turkey", "Japan" ];

function arrayString {
   // Your code here
}

// Should print "Canada, Mexico, Turkey and Japan"

console.log(arrayString(names));
```

I don't know where to start and we only know the .length method

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: A simple `for` loop over the array, and inside you compare the current loop iteration counter to the length of the array to figure out whether the current element is the last, second last - or “other.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a function that takes a parameter:

```
function arrayString(array) {}
```

Define a variable (eg. `var nameString = ""`) and then you can use a simple `for` loop:

```
function arrayString(array) {
   var nameString = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {       


        // if it is not the element before the last one, add a comma
        if ((i < array.length-2)) {
            // take the element on position i. arrays start on position 0
            nameString = nameString + array[i] + ", ";
            // a short version would be nameString += array[i] + ", ";
        } 
        // if it IS the element before the last one, add and
        else if (i === array.length -2) {
           nameString = nameString + array[i] + " and ";
        } 
        // the only uncovered element is the last one, therefore an else is enough
        else {
           nameString = nameString + array[i];
        }
    }
    // finally you  have to return the final string
    return nameString;
}
```

This should be a solution that would be appropriate for your level of knowledge i guess.

Hope this helps and have fun learning JavaScript.

**EDIT**: use [repl.it](https://repl.it/) to test your code. Simple tasks like yours can easily be tested and developed over here.

Comment: I thought about using for...in loop and .lenght method but after trying some things I've deleted my code because of feeling stupid

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: In JavaScript, if you want to iterate over an array, you should use `for..of` like in your example `for (var name of names)`. `for..in` is used to iterate over the keys of an object.